# How to Override base functionality of UserManager.GetRolesAsync(TKey userId)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-roles, asp.net-roles, security-roles

The base functionality for GetRolesAsync(TKey userId) is the following

```
        public virtual async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TKey userId)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var userRoleStore = GetUserRoleStore();
        var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).WithCurrentCulture();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.UserIdNotFound,
                userId));
        }
        return await userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    }
```

Does anyone know how to override this functionality in a derived class of UserManager or even provide a new Method like GetModelRolesAsync(string userId) to return a roleModel.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }

    public override async Task<IList<RoleModel>> GetRolesAsync(string userId)
    {
        // Need code here to return a RoleModel that includes the ID
        // as well as the role name, so a complex object instead of just
        // a list of strings


    }
}


public class RoleModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asp.Net Identity Entity Framework library provides an Identity Role Model out of the box called [`IdentityRole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityrole(v=vs.108).aspx).  You can use this in combination with the provided [`RoleManager` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468201(v=vs.108).aspx) to return the `IdentityRole` model.

You will have to provide your own function though, the interface for `Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TKey userId)` is set in the base class to return only strings.

Here is an example:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        _roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
    }

    public async Task<IList<IdentityRole>> GetModelRolesAsync(string userId)
    {
        IList<string> roleNames = await base.GetRolesAsync(userId);

        var identityRoles = new List<IdentityRole>();
        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            IdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
            identityRoles.Add(role);
        }

        return identityRoles; 
     }      
}
```

You can configure the system to use ASP.NET's built in dependency injection system for the RoleManager as shown [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/MightyZot/archive/2014/12/28/implementing-rolemanager-in-asp.net-mvc-5.aspx).

Comment: Perfect!   Thank you, just couldn't seem to connect the dots on that one!